# Filter Django query by week of month?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In a Django query, how would you filter by a timestamp's week within a month?

There's a built-in [week](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#week)  accessor, but that refers to week-of-the-year, e.g. 1-52. As far as I can tell, there's no other built-in option.

The only way I see to do this is to calculate the start and end date range for the week, and then filter on that using the conventional means.

So I'm using a function like:

```
def week_of_month_date(year, month, week):
    """
    Returns the date of the first day in the week of the given date's month,
    where Monday is the first day of the week.

    e.g. week_of_month_date(year=2022, month=8, week=2) -> date(2022, 8, 7)
    """
    assert 1 <= week <= 5
    assert 1 <= month <= 12
    for i in range(1, 32):
        dt = date(year, month, i)
        _week = week_of_month(dt)
        if _week == week:
            return dt
```

and then to calculate for, say, the 3rd week of July, 2022, I'd do:

```
start_date = week_of_month_date(2022, 7, 3)
end_date = week_of_month_date(2022, 7, 3) + timedelta(days=7)
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(created__gte=start_date, created__lte=end_date)
```

Is there an easier or more efficient way to do this with the Django ORM or SQL?

Comment: Well, the lookup table for any given year will only be 52 to 53 entries long; you could build up a `Case(When()))` tree to use in the query if your RDBMS doesn't have a suitable function otherwise.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why week of month (1-5) is important? Context might help to understand the end goal.

Comment: @Swift In my application, every day I need to update file collections for each week in the current month. As the date progresses, these collections get rotated out but the 1-5 group pattern remains. Maintaining collections for each week in a year would be a waste since I don't need them after the current month.

Comment: @Cerin thanks, I will update after work. I think I have an idea :) will run a test or two.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this using `datetime` objects is to quite simply subtract the current date weekly year value, with the yearly week value for the 1st day (or 1st week) of the month.

You can use the `.isocalendar()` function to achieve this:

```
dt.isocalendar[1] - dt.replace(day=1).isocalendar()[1] + 1
```

Basically if the week is 46 and that means the first week is week 44 then the resulting output should be 2.

### UPDATE

*I misunderstood the question, the answer is clear below. However, you may want to consider revising your function based on my above comments.*

Come to think of it, if you have a datetime object, you can get the isocalendar week and filter using that like so:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(created__week=dt.isocalendar()[1])
```

`dt.isocalendar()` returns essentially a tuple of 3 integers, `[0]`, is the year, `[1]`, is the iso week (1-52 or 53) and `[2]`, the day of the week (1-7).

As per the docs here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#week

There is a built-in filter for isoweek out of the box :)

However, filtering by "week of month" is not possible within the realms of "out of the box".

You might consider writing your own query expression object which accepts an isocalendar object and converts that? But I think you would be better off converting a datetime object and use the isoweek filter.

There's a neat little blog post here to get you started if you really want to do that:

https://dev.to/idrisrampurawala/writing-custom-django-database-functions-4dmb

Comment: It is not the week of the year, but the week of the month if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: I take on board you feedback and will consider rewriting my answer further. Thank you. Do feel free to take the answer, I'm pretty sure you have one :)